# Index/match formula not removing duplicate entries based on date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the following formula to search a table for all the results in a given month, filter out duplicates and return unique values. Its currently returning all values and not removing duplicates. Any help is greatly appreciated in correcting this formula.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX('Event List'!$B$3:$H$993,MATCH(0,NOT(DATE(YEAR($C$39),MONTH($C$39),1)=DATE(YEAR(Homework[Date]),MONTH(Homework[Date]),1))+COUNTIFS($B$40:$B40,Homework[Event],$C$40:$C40,Homework[Date],$D$40:$D40,Homework[Details],$E$40:$E40,Homework[Marketing Plan],June!$F$40:$F40,Homework[Assigned to Execute],June!$G$40:$G40,Homework[Notes]),0),COLUMN(B1)),"")}
```

[image: screen shot included]

[image: Expected result]

last picture is the expected result. I should have 6 unique values for the month.

Comment: Can you mock up some test data and expected output.  It may be easier for us to see what you want that way.

Comment: thanks Scott, just included a screen shot to assist with the question. The bottom portion "Monthly Summary" has my code with the column location changing. As you can see the dates in column C are different but the rest of the details are the same. Seems like the formula is not taking into account the date (month and year) to filter out the duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the formula wasnt working to filter "all" duplicate entries I used a pivot table instead. Same result I was trying to achieve with the formula above. Screen capture below:

[image]